# How to make label, textbox, combobox in C# Windows Forms accept and display chinese,japanese,korean and etc characters?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox, label

When I paste an chinese, japanese, korean text the textbox shows box character. How could I make displayed the character? What are the things to do?

Comment: Do you have those language packs installed in your Windows OS?

Comment: no, but it is not possible just to embed it in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .Net supports Unicode, and thus each of the languages you mention, make sure you use the correct font in your textbox. Depending on which language you target, there are different "preferred" fonts for each language.

See other questions here, such as

[Is Arial Unicode MS right font for WinForms UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3179603/21336)

[How to render unicode characters in the correct font? (C#/WinForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/103556/21336)

[Wikipedia on Unicode Fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font#List_of_Unicode_fonts)

Comment: where i can find those fonts?

Comment: either follow the font descriptions on the wikipedia page, or try one of the links I collected previously http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/free-unicode-fonts/